# inheritance and derived classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived

The compiler says that function dummy() on line 22 (in classs doumbClass) is ambiguous. How can I fix that?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

class BusinessClass {
    public :
        virtual void dummy(){
            cout<<"businessClass"<<endl;
        }
};

class EconomyClass {
    public:
        void dummy() {
            cout<<"economyClass"<<endl;
        }
};

class DoumbClass : public BusinessClass, public EconomyClass{
    public:
        void moreDumb(){
            dummy();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DoumbClass xclass;
    xclass.moreDumb();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: well which of the two do you want it to call? Or do you want it to call both? I think we can see it's quandry.

Comment: So the compiler is practically asking you *"which of the two do you mean?"*, and you are asking us how to "fix" that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify which base function you want to call
you can do this.

```
void moreDumb() {
    EconomyClass::dummy();
}
```

or

```
void moreDumb() {
    BusinessClass::dummy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can use Arkady Godlin method, You also can specify which `dummy` function you want to use in class declaration, if you know in advance. Like this :

```
class DoumbClass :public BusinessClass,public EconomyClass
{
public:
    using BusinessClass::dummy;
//or using EconomyClass::dummy;
};
```